# How can I reduce the spacing between columns in a table?

Tags: tables, tabularx

There are other similar questions, all with different answers, but I could not find one which achieves what I want. In the table below, the spacing between the numbers is too wide. How can I shrink it a bit?

```
\newcommand{\testmode}[2] {
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \textbf{#1} \\ \textbf{d=#2}
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{l | c c c | c c c |}
\cline{2-7}
          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Single}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Double}} \\
\cline{2-7}
          & \testmode{Scalar}{1} & \testmode{SSE-4}{4} & \testmode{AVX-2}{8} & \testmode{Scalar}{1} & \testmode{SSE-4}{2} & \testmode{AVX-2}{4} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Eytzinger}                        } &     209.86 &     370.18 &     411.25 &     180.85 &     245.37 &     262.61 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Classic Offset}                    } &     213.28 &     363.35 &     476.10 &     209.04 &     247.02 &     208.63 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Throughput in millions of searches per second with vector $X$ of size 15}
\label{tab:results0}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You can adjust `\tabcolsep` or write something like `@{\hskip.05cm}` between the column definitions. But to really help you it would be greatly appreciated to see a MWE.

Comment: Please always add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of only a code snippet. A compilable examples makes it easier to reproduce your problem without need for any speculation about additional needed or related code. So please help us to help you.

Comment: @TeXnician and @Jürgen: I think, the main problem is doubling `\tabcolsep` with the inner `tabular` (see my answer) and therefore no need to reduce the column separation of the outer `tabular`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example you have doubled the column separation using a `tabular` inside a `tabular`. Note: LaTeX adds a distance of `\tabcolsep` before and after each column. In your case you have such a distance before and after the column of the inner tabular of `\testmode` and before and after the column of the outer tabular. To avoid this, you should add `@{}` before the first column of the inner tabular and after the last column of the inner tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\testmode}[2] {%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}% Avoid doubling \tabcolsep
        \textbf{#1} \\ \textbf{d=#2}
    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{l | c c c | c c c |}
\cline{2-7}
          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Single}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Double}} \\
\cline{2-7}
          & \testmode{Scalar}{1} & \testmode{SSE-4}{4} & \testmode{AVX-2}{8} & \testmode{Scalar}{1} & \testmode{SSE-4}{2} & \testmode{AVX-2}{4} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Eytzinger}                        } &     209.86 &     370.18 &     411.25 &     180.85 &     245.37 &     262.61 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Classic Offset}                    } &     213.28 &     363.35 &     476.10 &     209.04 &     247.02 &     208.63 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Throughput in millions of searches per second with vector $X$ of size 15}
\label{tab:results0}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To explain some more: By default LaTeX adds `\hskip\tabcolsep` before it starts a column and after it has finished a column. So you have the distance `\tabcolsep` before the first and after the last column and `2\tabcolsep` between two columns. If you use `@{…}` the code of the argument of `@` is added *instead of the distance*. So `@{}` just removes the distance.

Additional note: I would recommend to avoid vertical rules in tables (see the manual of [package `booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)) and to use [package `siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for number columns. And I would not center the elements of the first table row but left-align them. And because `d=…` in the table head is something like math, you should set it in math mode. In this case I also would not make it bold (using, e.g., `\boldmath`), because font attributes in math have mostly a semantic (e.g, bold is often used for vectors or sets).

Comment: +1. I would also change `\textbf{d=#2}` to `$\mathbf{d=#2}$` in the definition of the `\testmode` macro.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. In reality I do not even need the nested table, I can just have two rows!

Answer (score 8):

I can't remember where I found this (edits with a reference are welcome), but adding the following directly before your `\begin{tabular}` statement can allow you to adjust the column spacing by a given value:

```tex
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0.4em}
```

You can use any unit here, but in the example above I use `em`, which is relative to the current font size.

Answer (score 0):

After five years ...

Now is available table package `tabularray` which for defining of column separation define `colsep` option. In comparison with "classic" table's code is shorter and text in cells better vertical spaced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hline{4,Z} = {0.8pt}, vline{1} = {4-Z}{solid},
              colsep = {4pt},  % <--- reduce tabcolsep from 6pt to 4pt
             colspec = {Q[l, font=\bfseries] | *{3}{X[c]} | *{3}{X[c]} |},
            row{1-3} = {font=\bfseries}
            }
    \cline[0.8pt]{2-Z}
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  Single
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  Double   
                    &   &                               \\
\cline{2-7}
    & Scalar & SSE-4 & AVX-2 & Scalar & SSE-4 & AVX     \\
    & D=1    & D=4   & D=8   & D=1    & D=4   & D=8     \\  
Eytzinger
    &209.86 &370.18 &411.25 & 180.85 & 245.37 & 262.61  \\
Classic Offset
    &213.28 &363.35 &476.10 & 209.04 & 247.02 & 208.63  \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Throughput in millions of searches per second with vector $X$ of size 15}
\label{tab:results0}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}l*{6}{X[c]}}[hvlines,corners=NW]
\RowStyle[bold,nb-rows=3]{}
    &   \Block{1-3}{Single}
        &   &   &   \Block{1-3}{Double} \\
    & Scalar & SSE-4 & AVX-2 & Scalar & SSE-4 & AVX     \\
    & D=1    & D=4   & D=8   & D=1    & D=4   & D=8     \\  
Eytzinger
    &209.86 &370.18 &411.25 & 180.85 & 245.37 & 262.61  \\
Classic Offset
    &213.28 &363.35 &476.10 & 209.04 & 247.02 & 208.63  \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Throughput in millions of searches per second with vector $X$ of size 15}
\label{tab:results0}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]