# How to get cleaner code for the division sum?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longdivision}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

\section {Even Numbers}

Even numbers are numbers that can be divided by two without leaving a remainder\\

\intlongdivision{912}{3}\\


\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
&&3&0&4\\
\hline
3&)&9&\cancel{1}&$^1{2}$\\


\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: (looks like you put in the effort to type the <div>s, but it would be better spent reading Markdown documentation which is/should be linked from the ask question page)

Comment: Anyway, for a start there are a few schemes (e.g. smash with overline, TikZ etc.) in [formatting - Better way to display long division? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131125/better-way-to-display-long-division?noredirect=1&lq=1) to shorten the bar, and maybe `@{}` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377502/how-can-i-reduce-the-spacing-between-columns-in-a-table for explanation)  to remove the space between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the classical division style of `xlop` package could be a problem, but otherwise produce a decent output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
\section*{Even Numbers}
Even numbers are numbers that can be divided by two without leaving a remainder:

\opdiv[style=text]{912}{3} →  \fbox{\parbox{7em}{%
\opdiv[maxdivstep=3, displayintermediary=all]{912}{3}}}

\end{document}
```